# How to return String[][] after finish splitting a string twice?

Tags: java, string, split

Suppose I am splitting a String, I would like to split by char 'E' first then split them by 'space' again.

```
String str = "30 3 3 11 5 2 2 7 9 2 1 20 E 21 2 2 11 14 5 2 1 7 3 6 E 30 4 3 11 5 21 2 15 20 3 17 9 5 1 32 E"
```

First split:

```
String[] first= str.split("E");
```

Second split:

```
for(int i=0; i<first.length; i++){
    String[] second = first[i].split(" ");
    return Second;
}
```

However this will only return the the string array at index 0. I would like to return the whole arrays.I tried to put the variable String[] Second outside of the loop. It does not work.

I would like the result to be the equivalent of:

```
String[][] result = {
        { "30", "3", "3" "11" "5" "2" "2" "7" "9" "2" "1" "20" },
        { "21", "2", "2" "11" "14" "5" "2" "1" "7" "3" "6" },
        { "30" "4" "3" "11" "5" "21" "2" "15" "20" "3" "17" "9" "5" "1" 32", "1", "32" }
};
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are returning from for loop. That's normal behavior.

Comment: The `return` statement kicks in in the first loop iteration, so it never reaches the next one. You have to split all items from `FirstSplit` first and then merge them into a single array, returning it outside the loop.

Comment: what is your expected output for this? Array or Arrays?

Comment: What does `FirstSplit` contain? Could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The for-loop is leaved already in the first iteration.

Comment: @johnll I expect Arrays , Sir

Comment: remove the return

Comment: OK what is the type of the "arrays" that you are expecting?

Comment: split by regex, you can split by "[\sE]+"

Comment: @StephenC String is good enough for me. I can convert it to integer later.

Comment: Wrong answer.  I mean do you expect a `String[][]` ... or something else?  As you can see, *some* people think you are asking for a `String[]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to split the string into an array of arrays of strings, then:

```
 String[] first= str.split("E");
 String[][] second = new String[first.length][];
 for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
     second[i] = first[i].split(" ");
 }
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Good catch that that the OP wanted the result as a String[][]. I edited the question to explain that.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String[][] result = Stream.of(str.split("E"))
        .map(firstSpring -> firstSpring.trim().split("\\s+"))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

To print the result :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

---

**Note :** I used `trim()` + `split("\\s+")` to avoid spaces in the result.

Comment: Ideally, when you know you have an array then you should be using `Arrays.stream` instead of `Stream.of` as this method is intended for accumulating values passed to it e.g. `Stream.of("1","2","3","4","5")` etc.. also, getting into the habit of using `Arrays.stream` will help prevent the cases where `Stream.of` returns unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you @Aominè I will put this in mind next time +1 for your answer as well

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to "split the string twice" (Which you can't really do without merging two arrays, because splitting a string returns an array anyways).

Java's [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method splits not by character, but by a **regex**. This means you can simply tell java to split by the character 'E' and ' ' (space) right off the bat.

```
String[] First= str.split("E| ");
```

The | operator in a regex is an "OR" operator. It'll look for anywhere in the string matching either 'E' or ' '.

Comment: That RegExp leaves two empty Strings for E's in the middle of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way if you only need a single String[] is to remove the `E`s before splitting by a space (avoiding complex regexps):

```java
String input = "E 30 3 20 E 21 2 1 32 E 5 E";
input = input.replace("E ", ""); // remove leading E
input = input.replace(" E", ""); // remove trailing E
input = input.replace(" E ", " "); // remove remaining Es
System.out.println(input); // 30 3 20 21 2 1 32 5

String[] result = input.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // [30, 3, 20, 21, 2, 1, 32, 5]
```

Comment: (If this was the OP's problem then `String[] First= str.split("(E| )+");` is a simpler way of doing it.  But I don't think it is the OP's problem.)

Comment: @StephenC That would leave an empty result if the input starts with an E. The RegExp quickly got complicated so I ditched it. But hey, the OP found his answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of [YCF_L's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402140/how-to-return-string-after-finish-splitting-a-string-twice/48402590#48402590) answer would be using the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) API.

```
String[][] resultSet =
                Pattern.compile("E")
                .splitAsStream(str)
                .map(e -> e.trim().split(" "))
                .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do and iterate twice like this.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Str = "30 3 3 11 5 2 2 7 9 2 1 20 E 21 2 2 11 14 5 2 1 7 3 
        6 E 30 4 3 11 5 21 2 15 20 3 17 9 5 1 32 E" ;
        String first[] =Str.split("E");
        String second[][]=convert(first);
        for(int i=0;i<second.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<second[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(second[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    public static String[][] convert(String[] first){
        String second[][] = new String[first.length][];
        for(int i = 0;i<first.length;i++){
            second[i] = first[i].split(" ");
        }
        return second;
    }
}
```

output:-

```
30 3 3 11 5 2 2 7 9 2 1 20 
 21 2 2 11 14 5 2 1 7 3 6 
 30 4 3 11 5 21 2 15 20 3 17 9 5 1 32
```